# Please help me with the name of this font

Tags: font-identification

I am looking for this font, I have tried to find it online and couldn't find a match. Does anyone know the name of this font?

Thanks in advance[image: Siganture]

Comment: *Often* signatures can be based on the *actual* signature of a person.. or they are created merely by some designer/artist actually drawing a signature. I know for my pieces a "font" is **never** used for any signature. I'll fire up Illustrator and, using my tablet, actually write the name. It may be in my overall handwriting, but it's never a "font" someone can match. I'm not saying this is the case here.. after all the `M`s are fairly identical. So the image in the question *may* be a font.

Comment: The sheer number of script fonts will make this hard to find, like looking for a needle in a haystack.  For example, Dafont has about 15000 script fonts alone.